# Excluding rows from an AGG() OVER(ROWS BETWEEN x PRECEDING) if they're related to the current row?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2017

I'm calculating a moving average of the last 100 sales of a particular item. I'd like to know if user X has spent more than 5 times everyone else combined, on that item in the last 100 sales window.

```
--how much has the current row user spent on this item over the last 100 sales?
SUM(saleprice) OVER(PARTITION BY item, user ORDER BY saledate ROWS BETWEEN 100 PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW)

--pseudocode: how much has everyone else, excluding this user, spent on that item over the last 100 sales?
SUM(saleprice) OVER(PARTITION BY item ORDER BY saledate ROWS BETWEEN 100 PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW WHERE preceding_row.user <> current_row.ruser)
```

Ultimately, I don't want the purchases made by my big spender to be factored into the total spend by the little spenders. Is there a technique that can exclude rows from a window, if they don't meet some comparison criteria versus the current row? (in my case, don't sum the saleprice from the preceding row if it bears the same user as the current row)

Answer (score 3):

This first one looks fine to me, except you're counting 101 sales.  *(100 preceding AND the current row)*

```
--how much has the current row user spent on this item over the last 100 sales?

SUM(saleprice)
  OVER (
    PARTITION BY item, user
        ORDER BY saledate
    ROWS BETWEEN 100 PRECEDING AND 1 PRECEDING   -- 100 excluding this sale
    ROWS BETWEEN  99 PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW   -- 100 including this sale
  )
```

*(Just use **one** of the two suggested `ROWS BETWEEN` clauses)*

In the second expression, you can't add a `WHERE` clause.  You can change the aggregation, the partition and the sorting, but I can't see how that would help you.  I think you need a correlated sub-query and/or use of `OUTER APPLY`...

```
SELECT
  *,
  SUM(saleprice)
    OVER (
      PARTITION BY item, user
          ORDER BY saledate
      ROWS BETWEEN  99 PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW   -- 100 including this sale
    )
      AS user_total_100_purchases_to_date,
  others_sales_top_100_total.sale_price
FROM
  sales_data
OUTER APPLY
(
  SELECT
    SUM(saleprice)  AS saleprice
  FROM
  (
    SELECT TOP(100) saleprice
      FROM sales_data       others_sales
     WHERE others_sales.user     <> sales_data.user
       AND others_sales.item      = sales_data.item
       AND others_sales.saledate <= sales_data.saledate
  ORDER BY others_sales.saledate DESC
  )
    AS others_sales_top_100
)
  AS others_sales_top_100_total
```

***EDIT:*** Another way to look at it, to make things come consistent

```
SELECT
  *,
  usr_last100_saletotal,
  all_last100_saletotal,
  CASE WHEN usr_last100_saletotal > all_last100_saletotal * 0.8
       THEN 'user spent 80%, or more, of last 100 sales'
       ELSE 'user spent under 80% of last 100 sales'
  END
      AS 
FROM
  sales_data
OUTER APPLY
(
  SELECT
    SUM(CASE top100.user WHEN sales_data.user THEN top100.saleprice END)   AS usr_last100_saletotal,
    SUM(                                           top100.saleprice    )   AS all_last100_saletotal
  FROM
  (
    SELECT TOP(100) user, saleprice
      FROM sales_data       AS others_sales
     WHERE others_sales.item      = sales_data.item
       AND others_sales.saledate <= sales_data.saledate
  ORDER BY others_sales.saledate DESC
  )
    AS top100
)
  AS top100_summary
```

Comment: This is somewhere between really hard and impossible to do with window functions, so I think `apply` is the most sensible method.